# Is it possible to allocate memory to dynamic array with specific indexes?

Tags: delphi

Let suppose I have dynamic array

```
type TCharArr = Array of byte;
type PcharArr = ^TCharArr;
var charArr: PcharArr;
```

Which I want to allocate memory in Heap in the way of New(charArr);

However, how can I specify size and indexes? Is it possible dynamic array to have indexes eg. from 512.. to 1024?

Comment: Declare the type as such, `type TCharArr = array[512..1024] of Byte;`. Otherwise it will be 0 based.

Comment: Victoria: So it is not possible to use the dynamic array for that purpose... OK.

Comment: A dynamic array with a range starting from a value <> 0 is not possible. You can still use a dynamic array if you have a function correcting the index, though.

Comment: @LU RD: The reason why I thought about it is that I have very big range, which is ~8.03 GB RAM. So I wanted to make smaller array - but I need to keep correct indexes which are greater than zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic arrays are always zero based. If you want to use array indices with a different base, then you would need to encapsulate the array access accounting for the offset to the indices. Something like this:

```
const
  Offset = 512;

function GetValue(Index: Integer): Byte;
begin
  Result := Arr[Index - Offset];
end;

procedure SetValue(Index: Integer; Value: Byte);
begin
  Arr[Index - Offset] := Value;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming a more recent Delphi version, you can mimic that with a generic record:

```
type
  TDynArray<T> = record
  private
    FData: TArray<T>;
    FOffset: Integer;
    function GetData(Index: Integer): T;
    function GetHigh: Integer;
    function GetLength: Integer;
    function GetLow: Integer;
    procedure SetData(Index: Integer; const Value: T);
  public
    constructor Create(ALow, AHigh: Integer);
    property Data[Index: Integer]: T read GetData write SetData; default;
    property High: Integer read GetHigh;
    property Length: Integer read GetLength;
    property Low: Integer read GetLow;
  end;

constructor TDynArray<T>.Create(ALow, AHigh: Integer);
begin
  FOffset := ALow;
  SetLength(FData, AHigh - ALow + 1);
end;

function TDynArray<T>.GetData(Index: Integer): T;
begin
  Result := FData[Index - FOffset];
end;

function TDynArray<T>.GetHigh: Integer;
begin
  Result := FOffset + System.High(FData);
end;

function TDynArray<T>.GetLength: Integer;
begin
  Result := System.Length(FData);
end;

function TDynArray<T>.GetLow: Integer;
begin
  Result := FOffset;
end;

procedure TDynArray<T>.SetData(Index: Integer; const Value: T);
begin
  FData[Index - FOffset] := Value;
end;
```

The usage could look then like this:

```
var
  arr: TDynArray<Integer>;
  I: Integer;
begin
  arr := TDynArray<Integer>.Create(512, 1024);
  for I := arr.Low to arr.High do
    arr[I] := I;

  for I := arr.Low to arr.High do
    Writeln(I, '=', arr[I]);
  Readln;
end;
```

Comment: `FData[FOffset + Index]` should probably be `FData[Index-Offset];`

Comment: @Uwe: BrakNiku is probably right. If the array is created as Create(3, 10)  (so in reality FData is 0..7) and you access arr[9], then you should access the internal array FData with index 6, not with index 12.

Comment: I have just fixed that

Comment: @David: OK. I didn't dare, because still I feel uncomfortable changing other people's code. I'm fine with improving a text part (or comment in code), but I won't touch code, unless there is an obvious error and I tried it myself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thanks for fixing it! Such things happen when you start fixing your code in the IDE after pasting it here and forget to synchronize it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition there is the concept of a [sparse array (sparse matrix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). Delphi does not support it out of the box, but there were implementations in TurboPower SysTools, if I remember correctly.

The source was put on SourceForge, when the company closed about 15 years ago:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools/

But these have not been updated for a looooong time.

This also seems to be the same library, maybe a bit more up to date:
https://github.com/TurboPack/SysTools

Comment: Sparse matrix and sparse array are quite different. Sparse array would be appropriate here. SysTools doesn't have sparse array or matrix so far as I can tell.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it's not called a sparse array but a sparse collection: 
SysTools: StColl.pas 4.04 <cr><lf> SysTools: Huge, sparse collection class

Comment: @DavidHeffernan regarding sparse array vs. sparse matrix: I must admit, I just put it into Google and took the Wikipedia link without actually reading the article. But it says "In numerical analysis and computer science, a sparse matrix or sparse array is a matrix in which most of the elements are zero.". If you assume "no value" -> "zero" then the article describes exactly what I meant.

Comment: sparse collection would be horribly inefficient for numerical work